# How to backup of all Table data from sql developer as scripts

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

How to backup of all Table data from sql developer as scripts,

I am going to truncate all the table to clean up the datas before to that i want to backup all the datas as scripts in my local folder.

Need to know:
-> How to backup of all Table data from sql developer as scripts,
-> How to truncate of all Table data at one shot

Thanks
Abinnaya

Comment: Tools - Database Export - Save As Separate Files. Check enable 'export data'.

Comment: Writing code that automates table truncation is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Writing code that automates table truncation is generally a bad idea. –  its just test database need to clean up the records to update live datas

Comment: then just drop the schema and recreate it

Comment: that not a good idea, thanks let me google it

Comment: How do you want to backup the tables, do you want it to be exported as a flat file or copy it in a different DB/Schema ?

Answer (score 0):

**DUMP ALL TABLES OF A SCHEMA**

You can use `expdp` util given by Oracle. All you have to do is open a command prompt and navigate to the SQLDeveloper installation directory and run the following command.

```
expdp username/password@database SCHEMAS=schema_name DIRECTORY=directory_name DUMPFILE=backup_file_name.dmp
```

This will dump all your table along with data in one go.

*Please change the values of `username`, `password`, `database`, `schema_name` etc. accordingly.*

**TRUNCATE ALL TABLES IN ONE SHOT**

Use the following anonymous block

```
BEGIN
  FOR tbl IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || tbl.table_name;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Please change the query accordingly and add `WHERE` if required.